# Passing data from 2 forms with the use of one submit button to the database

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, forms

I'm fairly new to PHP and HTML and its been 2 days since I've been trying to solve this problem.

I'm trying to pass the data from these forms into my database's table, but I can't manage to do so because both forms only use the same labels. 
[The 2 Forms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nIuh.png) 
[The table to which I'm trying to send the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZrxG.png)

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
    {   
        include('config/config1.php');
        global $conn; /* para makuha ang variable galing sa config/config1. */

        $firstname1 = $_POST["firstname"];
        $middlename1 = $_POST["middlename"];
        $lastname1 = $_POST['lastname'];
        $sex1 = $_POST['sex'];
        $household_head1 = $_POST['household_head'];
        $household1 = $_POST['household'];
        $civil_status1 = $_POST['civil_status'];
        $bday1 = $_POST['birthdate'];
        $bplace1 = $_POST['birthplace'];
        $citizenship1 = $_POST['citizenship'];
        $occupation1 = $_POST['occupation'];
        $sponsors_female1 = $_POST['sponsors_female'];
        $sponsors_male1 = $_POST['sponsors_male'];
        $email1 = $_POST['email'];
        $date_of_seminar1 = $_POST['date_of_seminar'];
        /****       Query       ****/
        $insrtBptm = "INSERT INTO parishioner (firstname,middlename,lastname,sex,household_head,household,civil_status,birthdate,birthplace,citizenship,occupation,sponsors_female,sponsors_male,email,date_of_seminar) 
                      VALUES ('$firstname1','$middlename1','$lastname1','$sex1','$household_head1','$household1','$civil_status1','$bday1','$bplace1','$citizenship1','$occupation1','$sponsors_female1','$sponsors_male1','$email1','$date_of_seminar1')";
        $update = "UPDATE parishioner SET Parishioner_idParishioner = idParishioner 
                   WHERE Parishioner_idParishioner IS NULL AND idParishioner IS NOT NULL";
        header("Location:Home.php");
        /****       Validation  ****/
        if(!mysqli_query($conn,$insrtBptm))
        {
            die("Error not queried". mysqli_error());   
        }
        if(!mysqli_query($conn,$update))
        {
            die("Update error !". mysqli_connect_error());
        }
        mysqli_close($conn);
    }
?>
```

Comment: You may use single form with all fields @Jake152

Comment: From your screen shot, the submit button posts only the data of the husband form.

Comment: Instead of using two form you should use single form
and for same fields for husband and wife you can use array
name ="wife[first_name]" and for husband name ="husband[first_name]"

of submission you will get two array wife and husband

Comment: You may use naming saperation like: your label name for both form so you should named for male like <input name="name[male]"> and female like <input name="name[female]">

Answer (score 0):

How I'd do it is, 
Create one single form with both the `Wife` and `Husband` and then prefix their `input` names with `wi_` and `hu_` **respectively**, And once the form is submitted then I'll process it on server-side and after validation/verification I'll make the query to insert two rows of data with respective inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Worry no more ! Create another second variable (ie: firstname2,middlename2, etc.. ) for php. Then do this magic

```
$insrtMar = "INSERT INTO parishioner (firstname,middlename,lastname,sex,household_head,household,civil_status,birthdate,birthplace,citizenship,occupation,sponsors_female,sponsors_male,email,date_of_seminar) VALUES ('$firstname1','$middlename1','$lastname1','$sex1','$household_head1','$household1','$civil_status1','$bday1','$bplace1','$citizenship1','$occupation1','$sponsors_female1','$sponsors_male1','$email1','$date_of_seminar1'),('$firstname2','$middlename2','$lastname2','$sex2','$household_head2','$household2','$civil_status2','$bday2','$bplace2','$citizenship2','$occupation2','$sponsors_female2','$sponsors_male2','$email2','$date_of_seminar2')";
```

So for short in query: INSERT INTO *tablename* (*columnnames*) VALUES (*1st php variables), (*2nd php variables)

Viola !